# Is a router itself contained in a component of physical layer in OSI reference model?

Tags: router

I understand that router is in L3. However, as a physical component does it correspond to a component of L1 (physical layer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While as a physical device a router needs to be able to implement all *physical* L1, *data link* L2 and *network* L3, its router functionality is purely L3: it needs to be aware of different networks and how to forward packets between them.

As in the end everything consists of physical devices, there wouldn't be any need to categorize devices based on that. More meaningful are the layers of the protocols the device or the software implements. For example, a web server / browser only implements *application layer* HTTP protocol and entrust the lower layers to the operating system and the hardware. Likewise, there's often a separate (L2) switch component inside consumer level routers.

Answer (score -1):

A router is entirely a software construct that filters/"routes" L3 traffic between networks. It has no physical components.

Answer (score -1):

Router is in L3(network layer) which has its IP address, but we can also consider it in L1 (physical layer), since it is an object. If some sort of problem occurs, while sending or receiving some data, the prob. can be in any one of the layer. But first we prefer to check the prob. in the first layer(which we can see, touch etc). Problems can also occur in the physical device itself also rather then the networks.So it do correspond to a component of layer 1.